# How to catch Django HTTP exceptions?

Tags: django

How catch and render the 404 error view when I raise Http404?

I want to create a similar exception like "WaitingForModeration" and then I would like to see this source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found myself using grep in django.core.handlers.base.BaseHandler

https://github.com/django/django/blob/0d0ccf81a0c18f42866d914672469f720861988a/django/core/handlers/base.py#L141

Comment: I was just writing an answer with that exact link. :)  Note that to add your `WaitingForModeration` exception, you probably want to [write a middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/#writing-your-own-middleware).